# Where can I see example sell-sheets for a game?

Tags: game-design, design-document

So my long term one-man indie project is turning into a two-man indie project, and I feel I need to take a step back and at least have a "sell-sheet" as a basis for the game design.

Does anyone have any good templates or tips?

Comment: What is a sell-sheet? Like a game design document (GDD)?

Comment: A sell-sheet is a one-page advertising pitch; in the domain of game design, it also probably covers your core vision for the game.

Comment: @Joe yep that's what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic structure is:

- One liner (aka Logline) - 1 sentence description of your game
- High Level Concept - Short paragraph giving an overview of the world/setting
- Gameplay - Short paragraph of your take on the genre, and 3-5 bullet points of key features

The difference between a 1 pager and a 4-5 pager is that each bullet point then gets a more detailed description explaining how it works. Sprinkle in any art you have where you can.

Unfortunately I can't share any real ones, but if you'd like to see some early documents from actual shipped games you should check out http://www.gamepitches.com. Lots of cool peaks at early pitch and design documents from shipped games.